# How to make a mount shared in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, shared-directory

I'm trying to start a project in Docker (directly from the Debian distro) in Windows 10 and getting this error:

```
$ docker compose up -d
[+] Running 0/0
 ⠋ Container core_php74_1  Creating                                                                                                                            0.0s
Error response from daemon: path /home/me/path/to/project is mounted on / but it is not a shared mount.
```

**How to make the mounted path `/home/me/path/to/project` a shared mount?**

Answer (score 59):

I got the same error after updating docker for desktop to 3.5.2 (66501). I have created volumes with trailing slashes in my `docker-compose.yml`. I removed them to fix the problem.

Change

```
volumes:
  - ./:/app/
  - ./another/folder:/folder/
```

To

```
volumes:
  - ./:/app
  - ./another/folder:/folder
```

Comment: Thanks a million Colin for your useful fix. I fixed the issue just like what you said. Don't know why it only affects Windows 10 with docker desktop 4.0.0 (67817) but it works on my Mac.

Comment: I just wanted to chime in that I was having this issue and it had to do with trying to seed my MySQL database with `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro`, which wasn't working anyways to automatically run my database seeds. Removing the `/:ro` resolved the issue for me.

Comment: @KyleCrossman You could've remove only the trailing `/` so your configuration would've be `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro`. `:ro` is for read-only

Comment: just want to report this happening on win10 docker desktop 4.2.0 (70708)

Answer (score 1):

You can NOT mount into docker to "/"
In your docker-compose.yml must be this lines or similar for windows :

```
volumes:
  - /home/me/path/to/project:/path/in/image
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this configuration is working on Linux hosts. So the mounting itself will be correct. Otherwise, it would not be possible to start the container(-s) anywhere.