# Unable to run docker compose from WSL 2 Ubuntu

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to run `docker-compose up -d --build` from Ubuntu (Windows WSL 2). I have enabled the WSL integration as per the steps listed [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/). Docker and compose are working from my  Ubuntu terminal as shown in the screenshot below but it gives me the error complaining that "Error response from daemon: path ... is mounted on / but it is not a shared mount". How should I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this answer for similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68455665/4676641

Comment: You posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69578573/4676641) too and have trailing slashes on your docker-compose so I think the previous link applies in this case

Comment: Yes, I posted previous question too. since nothing worked i tried to use wsl approach mentioned in one of the answers which did not work either.. entire day wasted by this docker. someone mentioned that re-installing may work. so trying that.

Comment: If you haven't tried already, you may want to remove the trailing `/` in your docker-compose volumes since your error seems very similar to the one discussed here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68455665/4676641

Comment: yes, I re-installed everything and removed the slashes too. it seems to work..

Comment: it worked but gave me another error down the road `Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown`. using sudo did not work

Comment: Please search for existing answers to that error or create a separate thread. The error is completely unrelated to the volume discussion. However, that seems like a permissions issue with your `entrypoint.sh` script and might be solved by `chmod +x entrypoint.sh`. I'd suggest moving further discussion to chat if that doesn't help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238158/discussion-between-vipin8169-and-tentative).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as an answer for easier reading.

As mentioned in the comments, the solution appeared to be removing slashes from volumes as suggested by [this similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68455665/4676641):

From this:

```
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/usr/src/app/
```

To this:

```
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src/app
```

Snippet from user's related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69578573/live-reload-does-not-work-in-docker-container-for-windows).